# Задача на сортировку строк в алфавитном порядке. Не проходит компиляцию (Out of bounds 21/35)

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

```
/* Задача по алгоритмам
    Задача: Введи с клавиатуры 20 слов и выведи их в алфавитном порядке.
   */

 public class Solution
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] array = new String[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = reader.readLine();
    }

    sort(array);  //21

    for (String x : array)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

public static void sort(String[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<array.length - i -1; j++)
        {
            isGreaterThan(array[j],array[j-1]);   //35
            String tmp =  array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

//Метод для сравнения строк: 'а' больше чем 'b'
public static boolean isGreaterThan(String a, String b)
{
    return a.compareTo(b) > 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Добавьте язык в метки к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j=0;    
       isGreaterThan(array[j],array[j-1]);
```

Будет попытка взять -1 элемент в массиве, о чём и предупреждает компилятор.

Comment: Спасибо. И if забыл добавить.